# Multi GPU Supercomputer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, gpu

I have a supermicro server running ubuntu server 14.04, and I would like to install a Quadro 400 (for display) a Nvidia GTX 295 and a Nvidia K80 however, when I install the driver for the K80 the Quadro 400 and Nvidia GTX 295 do not appear in nvidia-smi

When I try to install the drivers for the GTX 295 (which seem to be the same as the Quadro 400) from the nvidia website, it says that it needs to de-install the previously installed driver (even though the driver was for the K80 and not the GTX 295)

Any chance anybody has had this problem before ? and knows how to install and detect multiple-GPUs.

I have also created a (based on my previous searches) i have created a file called 
blacklist-nouveau.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/ containing the following

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

At the moment when running  nvidia-smi (and after having tried to install all drivers) i get the following message

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

1. I re-installed Ubuntu server 14.04
2. I followed point 1-2 and 3 from the official documentation

> ```
> cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux
> ```

3. I ran nvidia-smi which only showed me the K80
4. I unplugged the K80
5. I installed the drivers for the gtx295 and quadro 400 manually

> ```
>  sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
> ```

6. I replugged the K80
7. Restarted the system and ran Nvidia-smi (showing all graphic card but nothing seem to be accessible via CUDA code or Nsight)
8. so I re-ran (hoping the drivers of the GTX and Quadro would not be removed)

> ```
> sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers
> ```

9. Restarted the server

(at this point Nvidia-smi) only shows me the K80  .... again !

10. I finally installed

> ```
>  sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
> ```

11. I restarted the server
12. and yup, it worked, they are all detected and all GPUs are available.

All cards now appear in Nvidia-smi although I seem to have gained a graphical interface too, which is strange as I did not installed it, but fair does. I'll see if it works now.